# datetime and timedelta

Tags: python, datetime

My timezone is UTC+5.

So when i do datetime.datetime.now() it gives:

```
2012-07-14 06:11:47.318000
#note its 6AM
```

I wanted to subtract `5` hours from it so that it becomes equal to `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` so i did:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=time.timezone/60/60)
print dt
#gives 2012-07-14 11:11:47.319000

"""
Here 11 is not the PM its AM i double check it by doing
print dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
#gives 11:11:47 AM
"""
```

You see instead of subtracting 5 hours it adds 5 hours into datetime??
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try changing the `-` to a `+`

Comment: Yes that the question when i use + it actually subtracts, that is why i am confused??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're creating a negative timedelta. The value of `time.timezone` is negative:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.timezone
-36000
```

Here, I'm in UTC + 10, so your code becomes:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> print timedelta(hours=time.timezone/60/60)
-1 day, 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't noticed that the time.timezone is returning me the negative value.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.timezone) is clear:

> **time.timezone** The offset of the local (non-DST) timezone, in seconds west of UTC (negative in most of Western Europe, positive in the US, zero in the UK).

So positive UTC values have a negative timezone.